# Deploy a Jekyll site from Gitlab with Gitlab CD?

Tags: docker, jekyll, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I have a Jekyll blog which is in a repo on my self-hosted Gitlab server container. I would like to deploy it with Gitlab CD to a Docker container on the same Docker server (so that they're both behind my reverse proxy).

I can't find anything online about doing something like this. What I *think* should be done is build the Jekyll site in Gitlab CD, then push that generated site to an Nginx container on my Docker server OR push my code to a Jekyll container that builds it.

How would I push my code/the generated site to the other container in Gitlab CD?

Comment: I you are using Gitlab 8.16 (or above) then you should have Gitlab Pages as part of your installation. Check out https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/index.html#getting-started .

Comment: I don't want to use gitlab pages because I have a container that generates and maintains my Let's Encrypt certs and I want the jekyll site to be covered under that

Comment: You would need to provide more info on your setup because it's not clear right now what the layout is. I am not entirely convinced pages could not be used. 
That being said the push part of the solution would probably need to utilize SSH to get the files to a directory on the host of the Nginx container. The Nginx would need to mount that directory and serve the blog. See http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/ssh_keys/README.html for using SSH in a build environment.